# Trying to remember title of Novel(s) about a race of psychics that used to prevent pain on nearby planets

Tags: story-identification, novel

The novel started with a man trying to escape a society where being psychic was illegal. He succeeds and sets up a ranch where he has a lot of children and no blue eyed children can leave. This goes on for generations until one child is born with blue spots in brown eyes whom is allowed to leave but who had the unique ability to resist the psychic powers of their sibling.  Eventually that child spreads their genes to a space colony that goes about using their psychic abilities to prevent pain on nearby planets,  but have a crisis of conscience over it, feeling they are preventing the other plants from experiencing life naturally and stunting their progress. They essentially end themselves all except for one who travels to one of the nearby worlds to help them adjust to the new experience of pain.

On that planet there was a coming of age ceremony she the child would choose fire or ice and the men would try to throw them into either the freezing cold outside or into a fire.  Traditionally they would be physically unable to do so (when the psychics were preventing pain, they would be kind controlled to prevent the throw) by when the psychics stopped preventing pain,  the comming of age ceremonies where ending tragically, especially if the child chose fire.

There was a theme to the book that in order to know true joy one must contrast it with pain

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227442/anthology-series-with-suspended-animation-and-a-galaxy-wide-empire

Answer (score 16):

[The Worthing Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Worthing_Saga) by Orson Scott Card.

It has been asked about in [Novel with related stories, including one about an agrarian society where the elders can control thoughts to help cope with the loss of loved ones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246340/novel-with-related-stories-including-one-about-an-agrarian-society-where-the-el). The boy with the coloured eyes is Jason Worthing.

The trial that you mention is in the second story *The Making of Parchment and Ink*. The main protagonist is *Lared* and his father describes the trial as:

> “What is supposed to happen now?” asked Lared.
>
> Father looked sick. “We throw you in the fire. In the old days, we were stopped. Our arms would not do it, though we threw with all our might. We did it so we would remember the pain. And to test W-Worthing.”

The book is a collection of loosely connected stories and is a little incoherent as a result.

Comment: I've seen a whole bunch of questions about the Worthing Saga lately. Nice.